# .VisualElementsManifest.xml for start screen tiles ignored using Inno Setup

Tags: windows-8, inno-setup, shortcut-file

I'm using Inno Setup to create an installer for my app.
Creating shortcuts on the windows 8 start screen works fine using [Icons].
But now I'd like to customize the tiles using a VisualElementsManifest.

I believe I followed all of the steps here: "How to customize Start screen tiles for desktop apps"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx#create_the_customization_xml_file

However, when I compile my installer and run it, the VisualElementsManifest is ignored.
The tile shows up on the start screen with a regular icon as defined in the Inno Setup iss-file (IconFilename).

Following steps were taken to create custom tile for MyApp.exe:

```xml
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <VisualElements
        BackgroundColor="#E82C2A"
        ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="off"
        ForegroundText="light"
        Square150x150Logo="logo.MyApp.150x150.png"
        Square70x70Logo="logo.MyApp.70x70.png"/>
</Application>
```

File saved as MyApp.visualelementsmanifest.xml in the same directory as MyApp.exe.

Configure Inno Setup:

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApp
AppVersion=0.1
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApp
SetupIconFile=MyApp.ico

[Files]
Source: "MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyApp.exe.manifest"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyApp.ico"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "logo.MyApp.150x150.png"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "logo.MyApp.70x70.png"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyApp.visualelementsmanifest.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\appfolder\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe";
Name: "{commonprograms}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe";
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe";
```

Compile installer and run it.. no luck.

Comment: It also works for me. Of course the images are shown only on *Start* screen. Not on the *Apps* one. From that style you will see only the `BackgroundColor` attribute and nothing more on the *Apps* screen. If you pin the application to the *Start* screen, you should see your image. If not, you're providing wrong images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a [`customization XML file`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx#create_the_customization_xml_file) with the following content (it's the necessary minimum shown in the linked article):

```xml
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <VisualElements
        BackgroundColor="#FF0000"
        ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="on"
        ForegroundText="light"/>
</Application>
```

and saved it as `MyProg.visualelementsmanifest.xml` since the program I'll install is `MyProg.exe` (I've used the one from the Inno Setup's `Examples` subfolder but it should not matter; important here is naming of the XML file according to that executable). My script looked like this (again, just the necessary minimum):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.visualelementsmanifest.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

I've tested on Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit (running on virtual machine) and it worked as expected. I've checked the *Apps* screen as well as the *Start* one (if you select *Pin to Start* option in *Apps* screen). Even updating worked as expected, so try to build your setup from this minimum (check if the XML file has the minimum attributes I've used here and check if the name of the XML file equals to the expected pattern).

Comment: after completely reinstalling windows, your example worked perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning "naming of the XML file according to executable" got it working.